# Is there any way to use closure in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create function inside function for closure in Angular 4.

> When i tried to do the below i am getting error as "cannot find name
>   innerFn"

```
outerFn(){
  let a = "hello";
  innerFn(){
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me on this ?

Comment: `function innerFn(){..` are you trying to access it outside of `outerFn` ?

Comment: Thanks @echonax. Its working.

Comment: No I am not trying to access it outside of 'outerFn'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `function` keyword:

```
outerFn(){
  let a = "hello";

  var that = this; // use that to access the component
  function innerFn(){
    console.log(a);
  }

  innerFn(); // will log a
}
```

**Warning:** if you try to use `this` inside this function it will not refer to your component because of the closure.

Comment: Is there any way to access `this` of component inside the function ? @echonax

Comment: @RajarajanKamban I've updated the answer. You can use the `that` variable. Notice that you assign `this` to it outside of the function